# R package "repmis" crashes R on library(repmis)

Tags: r

I tried installing a list of packages this morning and had an error which crashed R when I ran library(repmis)

```
install.packages("repmis")
library(repmis)
```

I've uninstalled & reinstalled R (on my mac by deleting the app and downloading the new build), but still get an app crash when I run library(repmis).

Can anyone tell me why? And/or how I can more effectively uninstall R to get this package to work again?

Comment: what build of R are you using? did you set a cache directory?

Comment: 3.1.1, It doesn't give the option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I restarted the computer and repeated the procedure above and this time received a prompt to install a Java 6 runtime.

I'm guessing that the dialogue box had issues displaying earlier because of some system printer windows I had open.